# How to fix <Response [404]> error when I sent a post request

Tags: python, json, post, beautifulsoup, request

I want to get data from the site, but the response only shows  error.

I tried changing the url to http which led to 405 error, and tried data=json.dumps(data) to just data = data, but they all didn't work.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request_url = 'https://www.kinds.or.kr/news/newsResult.do'

data = {"jsonSearchParam": {"indexName": "news", "searchKey": "sky", "searchKeys": [{}], "byLine": "", "searchFilterType": "1", "searchScopeType": "1", "mainTodayPersonYn": "", "startDate": "2019-05-06", "endDate": "2019-08-06", "newsIds": [
], "categoryCodes": [], "incidentCodes": [], "networkNodeType": "", "topicOrigin": ""}, "index-name": "news", "N": "", "search-keyword": "sky", "search-index-type": "news", "dict-type": "texanomy", "dict-concat": "OR"}

response = requests.post(request_url, data=json.dumps(data))

html = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

flist = soup.find_all('span')

print(response)
```

I expect to get proper response.

Comment: 404 HTTP status code means that the requested resource cannot be found by server. Are you sure you're sending right request? Try to make this POST request for example in [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) first to inspect situation in more details.

Answer (score 0):

Your url seems to be incorrect. Looking into Firefox developer tools, the correct URL for searching is `'https://www.kinds.or.kr/v2/news/search.do'`. The parameters "jsonSearchParam" needs to be a json string, so we use `json.dumps()` on it:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# request_url = 'https://www.kinds.or.kr/news/newsResult.do'
request_url = 'https://www.kinds.or.kr/v2/news/search.do'   # <-- correct URL

d = {"indexName": "news", "searchKey": "sky", "searchKeys": [{}], "byLine": "", "searchFilterType": "1", "searchScopeType": "1", "mainTodayPersonYn": "", "startDate": "2019-05-06", "endDate": "2019-08-06", "newsIds": [], "categoryCodes": [], "incidentCodes": [], "networkNodeType": "", "topicOrigin": ""}
data = {"jsonSearchParam": json.dumps(d), "index-name": "news", "N": "", "search-keyword": "sky", "search-index-type": "news", "dict-type": "texanomy", "dict-concat": "+OR+"}

response = requests.post(request_url, data=data)
print(response)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
flist = soup.find_all('span')
print(flist)
```

Prints:

```
<Response [200]>
[<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>, <span class="icon-bar"></span>, <span class="icon-bar"></span>, <span class="icon-bar"></span>, <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>, <span class="input-group-addon">
<i class="fal fa-envelope"></i>
</span>, <span class="input-group-addon">

...and so on.
```